# How to compare two 24Points game expressions?

Tags: c#, algorithm, math

I wrote, in C#, some code to get all valid expressions of 24Point games. And some expressions are actually the same, but my code can't tell. How can I compare them in order to remove duplicated expressions?

For example,

2 + 3 + 9 + 10

2 + 3 + 10 + 9

10 / 2 * 3 + 9

10 * 3 / 2 + 9

The expression1 and expression2, expression3 and expression4 are actually the same (duplicated).
I have totally more than 10 thousands expressions.

1. I tried several solutions, for example, if two expressions contains same 4 integers (doesn't care the order) and same 3 operators (no order required either), but this way, some unique expressions are removed.
2. I also thought about using mid-results. For example, "10 / 2 * 3 + 9", firstly, 10 / 2 = 5, secondly, 5 * 3 = 15, so 5 and 15 are so-called mid-results. If two expressions have the same mid-results, then I see them as same expressions. But this doesn't work either, for example, 2 * 2 + 10 + 10 and 2 + 2 + 10 + 10, they are not same, but the solution will see them as same.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end you need to evaluate the expressions to catch all cases.
This shouldn't be too slow.

Only if that is to slow I would wast time on detection kommutativity of addition or multiplication. (And I'm not at all sure if this will improve the speed)

Cases like `2*2` = `2+2` are very rare and most likely now worth the effort to detect them.

Comment: Thank you, so far, I couldn't find any other case like 2*2=2x2, maybe it's the right way to do it if I take care of "2" specifically.

Comment: Other case:  1*1 = 1/1 : If 0 is also possible 0+0 = 0*0 = 0-0 . x /1 = x*1 (for all x)

Comment: Tried to list all similar cases, still so far, I think this can be the right way. Thanks so much.